# Change margin only for bibliography pages

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I write document with margins:

```
left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=4cm,bottom=4cm,
```

but I would like to have bibliography margins like

```
left=2cm,right=2cm,top=4cm,bottom=4cm
```

Comment: Usually consistency trumps other worries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `geometry`'s `\newgeometry` (and `\restoregeometry`).

Declare the normal page layout in the preamble and then set the layout for the bibliography with `\newgeometry`. Since a new page layout only really works on a new page we issue `\cleardoublepage` before we change the margins.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=4cm, bottom=4cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum

\nocite{*}

\cleardoublepage
\newgeometry{left=2cm, right=2cm, top=4cm, bottom=4cm}
\printbibliography

\cleardoublepage
\restoregeometry
% not really needed if there is nothing after the bibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very mutch @moewe. this is exactely wath i need